# UITextView Font reversing back to System Default

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, fonts

I have set up a custom font for the UITableView overall in my app. I wrote this in my AppDelegate

```
UITextView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14.0)
```

So that the font of all of the UITextView's changes to that custom font.

So when I load my app, the font appears as system font in the home page, but everything else has the custom font, if I go to a different view in the app and I go back to the home page for a brief moment I see the custom font

[image: Custom font shown for a brief time]

but then after the background app refresh it goes back to this:

[image: System font]

I'm not exactly sure what's going on in here. The other textViews have the custom font, and there's nothing messing around with the front in the background refresh either.

**Note:** The only font that changes back to system default is the black one, the other ones are labels and are working fine.

Any help would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to click on selectable in the UITextView in the Storyboard. It works good now!